# Параллельный запуск Test Suites

Tags: java, maven, selenium, junit, test-automation

У меня есть два класса (`TestSuite1 и TestSuite2)`, следующей конструкции:

```
import org.junit.runners.Suite;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses({TestClass1.class, TestClass2.class})
public class TestSuiteOne {
  //nothing
}
```

Как запустить их на выполнение параллельно при помощи `maven-surefire-plugin`?

Или, возможно, моя попытка изначально не верна, в таком случае буду рад другим предложениям.

Answer (score 0):

Если посмотреть документацию для плагина [maven-surefire-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/fork-options-and-parallel-execution.html), то можно заметить, что у него имеется настройка задающая количество тредов, в которых будут выполняться тесты:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.22.0</version>
  <configuration>
         <forkCount>3</forkCount>
         <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
         <parallel>classes</parallel>
         <threadCountClasses>1</threadCountClasses>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

По умолчанию значение для `forkCount` равно `1`

Comment: У Вас, наверное, не хватает параметра `<parallel></parallel>`. В pom файле у меня выставлен параллельный запуск 5 тест сьютов. Проблема же состоит в том, что бы запустить тесты на выполнение из консоли. 
 `mvn clean test -Dtest=TestSuiteOne` - запускает один тест сьют. А о `mvn clean suite`, мавен, к сожалению, не знает

Comment: @PavelBobrov поправил ответ

Comment: я все ровно не понимаю как мне это поможет. У меня нет проблем с параллельным запуска классов. Maven просто запускает все классы со словом test в имени.  Как мне проделать тоже самое со сьютами?

Comment: Сьюты в плагине не поддерживаются. Юзай категории - вот здесь пример (https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/junit.html)  запускается вот  `mvn -Dgroups=my-group-name test`